# jquery - expand google map when scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

So, i have split page:

one side - sections with texts and locations

other side - google map with pins referring to the sections

I add script that expand the map height when you scroll down, but it's not so intuitive.

Is there any better code than can open expand the map while user scroll down?

This is my current code:

```
// change map size when scroll down
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 450) {
        $("#map-warp").addClass("change-map-canvas");   // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "40px"); ;     // change margin from top for close infoWindow button
    } else {
        $("#map-warp").removeClass("change-map-canvas");  // removed the . from class
        $("#map-warp").css("margin-top", "10px"); ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

bind window scroll , whene scroll to end  trigger  if = true

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
              //scroll in the end
             if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.documentElement.offsetHeight)) {
               //dosomething
               }

        });
```

Comment: add some explanation to your answer